# Change collection cursor to array of objects in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, collections

I have a collection `Projects`.

I want to print all projects as an array with objects

```
{
  value: _id,
  label: name
}
```

I have tried

```
var projects = Projects.find().fetch();

Object.keys( projects ).map( function ( key ) {
  return {
    value: projects[key]._id,
    label: projects[key].name
  };
} );
```

It works but is it the best way to do it?

I think I have seen that the collection has a direct `map` function.

Answer (score 0):

What about `forEach` usage ?

```
projects.forEach(function(project) {
  return {
    value: project._id,
    label: project.name
  };
});
```

Comment: I guess that's a bit better, but what about mapping directly on `Projects.find()`?

Comment: I have tried `    return Projects.find().map( function ( project ) {
      value: project._id,
      label: project.name
    } );
`

Comment: @Jamgreen You forgot about `.fetch()`

Comment: Oh. It seems to work with `return Projects.find().map( function ( project ) {
      return {
        value: project._id,
        label: project.name
      };
    } );` :D